# Are there ideas about Multiverse in cosmology that are independent of string theory?

Tags: cosmology, multiverse

It is known that string theory allows for many kinds of universes within it's *Landscape* which give rise to the concept of the multiverse. But are the concepts/ideas about multiverse in cosmology which have nothing to do with string theory and still allows for *many* kinds of universes, each with different set of physical constants and properties?

Comment: See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiverse M-theory is just one type of multiverse model.